# Why does the child proccess execute after the parent with execlp?

Tags: c, shell, fork, exec

I have this projet for my school where I'm supose to make a minishell in C using fork and the exec function.
My main can only take a string as argument and I'm limited to this headers:
stdio.h, unistd.h, stddef.h, sys/wait.h, err.h, sys/types.h, errno.h, assert.h

Here is what I've done so far.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <err.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // EX: argv = {"main", "echo Hello"};
{
    if (argc != 2)
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of arguments.\n");
    
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        int wstatus;
        int child_pid = waitpid(pid, &wstatus, 0);
        printf("process exit status: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(wstatus));
    }
    else
        execlp("/bin/sh", "## PROGRAM NAME ##", "-c", argv[1], NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is:

```
42sh$ ./main 'echo Hello'
Hello
process exit status: 0
```

I manage to execute the given command, however the output I get for the same example is:

```
42sh$ ./main 'echo Hello'
process exit status: 85
Hello
```

I dont understand why the 'Hello' is print after the exit status giving the fact that I used 'wait' in the parent proccess. Also I don't know why the exit status is not 0 as expected ?

Thank you for taking the time to answers me ! This is my first question so I hope that I did this the right way.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Is this the **exact** code you're running?  Did you recompile?

Comment: You have the logic backwards. `fork()` returns 0 to the child, so the child is calling `waitpid()` and the parent is calling `execlp()`.

Comment: That worked well ! Thank you